# “what kind(s) of” vs. “what type of”

Tags: grammar

When should we need to use “what kind(s) of” or “what type of”

e.g

> What **kind** of food did you have there?
> What **type** of food did you have there?

Which one is better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are subtle differences between **type** and **kind**, but they can often be used interchangeably, especially when talking about food, as in your example:

> What type of food did you have there?
>
> What kind of food did you have there?

Either is acceptable and there is no difference in meaning. In general, when either word can be used, **type** is slightly more formal than **kind**, so you might hear **kind** more often in spoken English, but you'll probably see **type** more often in written English.

In cases where you might choose one over the other, you typically use **type** to reference specific things (characteristics, traits, qualities) that distinguish group members from one another. For example:

> He has a type "A" personality.

Everyone in the group has some type of personality. Some have type "A", others have type "B" and a different group might have type "C." It's the type that distinguishes one from the other.

**Kind** is typically used to associate an individual with a group. For example:

> What kind of ninja do you want to be for Halloween?

The differences are extremely subtle, and I think you can almost always use **type** in place of **kind** and get away with it. But there are specific cases where you cannot use **kind** in place of **type**, so when in doubt, use **type**.

Comment: I might add that "type" to me connotes the existence of somewhat distinct classes, as opposed to "kind" which describes a more general nature without affixing a label. If you get terrible service at a restaurant, for example, you might ask the manager "What kind of a restaurant is this, anyway?", which is making a comment about the general character of the restaurant, rather than the style of food they serve (which might be implied by "what type of a restaurant is this?").